# C# - Byte array to Hex string

Tags: c#, string, hex, memory-editing

I am making a trainer for Modern Warfare 2. The problem I am having is the conversion of hex to string, I am fairly new to this but I do look around before I try anything. I have also looked around before posting this question. Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int xbytesRead = 0;
    byte[] myXuid = new byte[15];
    ReadProcessMemory((int)processHandle, xuidADR, myXuid, myXuid.Length, ref xbytesRead);
    string xuid = ByteArrayToString(myXuid);
    textBox2.Text = xuid;
}

public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
{
    string hex = BitConverter.ToString(ba);
    return hex.Replace("-", "");
}
```

The return value I am getting is: `330400000100100100000000000000`

But I need it to return this: `110000100000433`

Any suggestions?

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa

Comment: @Greenonion: Where do you think OP got that code from? Can't imagine many people use `ba` as a parameter name

Comment: It seems a Little Endian vs Big Endian issue. http://people.cs.umass.edu/~verts/cs32/endian.html

Comment: @Greenonion  have already seen that topic. Thats where i got the conversion from but i'm puzzled on getting it from :330400000100100100000000000000
to : 110000100000433

Comment: FYI, the modern warfare bit has no bearing on the question. It doesn't need to be mentioned

Comment: @musefan sorry I thought it would be polite to give a bit of information on what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a Little-Endian vs Big-Endian issue.  Please try the following:

```
public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
{
    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
         Array.Reverse(ba);

    string hex = BitConverter.ToString(ba);
    return hex.Replace("-", "");
}
```

---

References:

- [BitConverter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [An Essay on Endian Order](http://people.cs.umass.edu/~verts/cs32/endian.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why dont use int?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
int xbytesRead = 0;
byte[] myXuid = new byte[15];
ReadProcessMemory((int)processHandle, xuidADR, myXuid, myXuid.Length, ref xbytesRead);
string xuid = ByteArrayToString(myXuid);
textBox2.Text = xuid;
}

public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
{
  int hex=0;
  for(i=0;i<ba.Length;i++)
     hex+=Convert.ToInt(ba[i])*Math.Pow(256,i)
  return hex.ToString("X");
}
```